# How to stop asynchronous tcp .NET code from using up an entire system's resources

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, tcp

In some asynchronous tcp server code I have, occasionally an error occurs that causes the process to consume the entire system's memory.  In looking at the logs, event viewer and some [MS docs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947862) the problem happens if "the calling application makes Asynchronous IO calls to the same client multiple times then you might see a heap fragmentation and private byte increase if the remote client stops its end of I/O" which results in spikes in memory usage and pinning of System.Threading.OverlappedData struct and byte arrays.

The KB article's proposed solution is to "set an upper bound on the amount of buffers outstanding (either send or receive) with their asynchronous IO."

How does one do this?  Is this referring to the byte[] that are sent into BeginRead?  So is the solution simply wrapping access byte[]'s with a semaphore?

EDIT: Semaphore controlled access to byte buffers or just having static sized pool of byte buffers are two common solutions.  A concern I have that still remains is that when this async client problem occurs (maybe it's some weird network event actually) having semaphores or byte buffer pools will prevent me from running out of memory, but it does not solve the problem.  My pool of buffers will likely get gobbled up by the problem client(s), in effect locking correct function legitimate clients out.

EDIT 2: Came across this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830417/manually-unpinning-a-byte-in-c).  Basically it shows how to manually unpin objects.  And while asynchronous TCP code leaves pinning up to behind the scenes runtime rules, it might be possible to override that by explicitly pinning each buffer before use, then unpinning at the end of the block or in a finally.  I'm trying to figure that out now...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236171/net-does-not-have-reliable-asynchronouos-socket-communication

Comment: That's about wrapping call to BeginRead with semaphore.

Comment: Maybe this is a good reason to profile the code...

Comment: @giacomo I wish I had a profiler.

Comment: Stop wishing and just download an eval or free profiler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Comment: ...my ANTS expired awhile ago.  But yeah I'm trying to find a decent free alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of addressing the problem is by pre-allocating buffers and other data structures used in async communications. If you preallocate on startup, there will be no fragmentation, since the memory will naturally reside in the same area of the heap.

I recommend using `ReceiveAsync`/`SendAsync` APIs added to .Net 3.5 SP1, which allows you to cache or pre-allocate both the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` structure and the memory buffer stored in `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Buffer` property, unlike the older `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX` APIs which only allow caching or pre-allocating the memory buffer.

Using the old API also incurred significant CPU costs, because the API internally created Windows Overlapped I/O structures again and again. In the new API this takes place within `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, and so by pooling these objects, the CPU cost is paid only once.

Regarding your update on pinning: pinning is there for a reason, namely to prevent GC from moving the buffer during defragmentation. By unpinning manually, you may cause memory corruption.